# Foundations Tabbar Dropdown is Falling behind "Intro" Secton

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation, tabbar

http://maurabrennandesigns.com/OO/

The tab bar is not working because the drop down is falling behind the "intro" section. How do I fix this or bring the tab bar drop down forward?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide much more details then you did especially if you want help. Give the html, css and js/jQuery that is relevant to what you are working on. What you essentially gave us was a site to go debug which on SO is not usually meant with any good responses (for good reasons).

With all that said I did do a quick look. You would need to include the top-bar js as described in the docs. Also once you start using foundation js you need to call the foundation function on the document. Again I am not sure if this will fix anything but it is a start (if it does mark this answered if not add more details for more help).

All the way at the bottom of this page you will see this
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<!-- Other JS plugins can be included here -->

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```